# Idiomatic way to long multistring constants (or vars) in Lisp code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, heredoc

What is idiomatic way for inserting long multistrings vars or constants in Common Lisp code?
Is there something like HEREDOC in unix shell or some other languages, to eliminate indenting spaces inside string literals?

For example:

```
(defconstant +help-message+ 
             "Blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah
              some more more text here")
; ^^^^^^^^^^^ this spaces will appear - not good
```

And writing this way kinda ugly:

```
(defconstant +help-message+ 
             "Blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
some more more text here")
```

How we should write it. If there any way, when you don't need to escape quotes it'll be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about idiomatic, but `format` can do this for you.  (naturally.  `format` can do anything.)

See Hyperspec section 22.3.9.3, Tilde newline.  Undecorated, it removes both newline and subsequent whitespace.  If you want to preserve the newline, use the `@` modifier:

```
(defconstant +help-message+
   (format nil "Blah blah blah blah blah~@
                blah blah blah blah blah~@
                some more more text here"))

CL-USER> +help-message+
"Blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
some more more text here"
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @coredump And in the case of a a constant string, you can use #. (as in [Rainer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26278029/1281433)).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing.

Indentation is usually:

```
(defconstant +help-message+ 
  "Blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
some more more text here")
```

Maybe use a reader macro or read-time eval. Sketch:

```
(defun remove-3-chars (string)
  (with-output-to-string (o)
    (with-input-from-string (s string)
      (write-line (read-line s nil nil) o)
      (loop for line = (read-line s nil nil)
            while line
            do (write-line (subseq line 3) o)))))

(defconstant +help-message+
  #.(remove-3-chars
  "Blah blah blah blah blah
   blah blah blah blah blah
   some more more text here"))

CL-USER 18 > +help-message+
"Blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah blah
some more more text here
"
```

Would need more polishing... You could use 'string-trim' or similar.

Comment: Year, i thought about making similar macro, but it'll break things if someone edits code in other editor with different indentation settings.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use this form:

```
(concatenate 'string "Blah blah blah"
                     "Blah blah blah"
                     "Blah blah blah"
                     "Blah blah blah")
```

Comment: This will give you: "Blah blah blahBlah blah blahBlah blah blahBlah blah blah", without newlines.